# DAX SUMMARIZECOLUMNS FILTER NOT IN or DOES NOT CONTAIN

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am writing a DAX query, and trying to filter out values that contain the word "OPEN"

```
EVALUATE
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
    Salesforce[SalesPersonName],
    FILTER ( 'Salesforce', Salesforce[SalesPersonName] <> "OPEN" )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `CONTAINSSTRING`?

```
EVALUATE
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
    Salesforce[SalesPersonName],
    FILTER (
        'Salesforc`enter code here`e',
        NOT ( CONTAINSSTRING ( Salesforce[SalesPersonName], "OPEN" ) )
    )
)
```